# Redirecting buttons with values to other django templates/views

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Firstly, I am getting a csv file from the user. 
(Template file:)

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'rowcol' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

Then i am generating a list of all the columns present in the file and then calling another html file. (views.py:)

```
def rowcol(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['file']
        dataset=pd.read_csv(file)
        lst=list(dataset)
        return render(request, 'Link5_rc.html', {'arr':lst})
    return HttpResponse('')
```

In that html file, i am creating buttons for all the columns present.(Link5_rc.html:)

```
{% for link in arr %}
<form action=" " method="post">
<button name="{{link}}" type="submit" value="{{link}}">{{link}}</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the following is the part where i am stuck:   I want these buttons to redirect to another html page or maybe a view in views.py , where i can show to the user which column he/she selected and then perform further actions on that particular column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass one or more values to the request as in the following example:

```
<a href="{% url 'your_url_alias' value_1='1' %}">Some text</a>
```

You can use variables like:

```
<a href="{% url 'your_url_alias' value_1=column.id %}">Some text</a>
```

In your app urls.py you should set the following to receive the extra data in the request:

```
url(r'^your_name/(?P<value_1>[\d\D]+)$', views.your_view, name="your_url_alias")
```

Then, in your view function you should receive the data as in:

```
def your_view(request, value_1):
```

An then you can use the value to filter the queryset.